# How to compare two strings with the != operator and store the result in a variable called my_boolean?

Tags: python, string, variables, boolean, operator-keyword

I'm not sure I understand what they're asking me to do here, so this is my attempt at doing it.

```
a='Swim'
b='Run'
if a!=b:

    my_boolean = a!=b
    print (my_boolean)
```

Comment: Get rid of the `if a!= b:` test, and simply perform the assignment always.  As it is, you're failing to do the assignment when `a` and `b` are equal, so it only works when they're unequal.  It's not as complicated as you're making it.  Just `a='Swim'`, then `b='Run'`, then `my_boolean = a != b`.  That's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

the excercise is only asking you to save the value of 'a!=b' in a variable.

However this should help you to understand the code better; you should save 'a != b' only once and then use 'my_boolean' every time you need it, but your code only prints true, because if 'my_boolean' is false, try this:

```
a = 'Swim'
b = 'Run'
my_boolean = a != b
print(my_boolean)
if my_boolean:
    print('printing result: ' + str(my_boolean))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's get through it one-by-one. You are trying to compare two strings. If they are exactly the same you should get `True` otherwise you get `False`. Doing so would result in a Boolean or `bool` value.

So, your solution is inverted. It is expected to be:

```py
a='Swim'
b='Run'
my_boolean = (a==b) # This value is boolean already. You can remove the brackets too. I put them for clarity
print (str(my_boolean)) # It works without saying str(), but I did that to show you that the value is converted from the type `bool` into the type String `str`.
```